# Find a real-valued function which satisfied Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

**Question:** Find a real-valued function $v(x,y)$ such that $v(0,0)=1$ and together, $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations in the entire complex plane.

Let $v(x,y)=M(x,y)+i.0$ which is a real-valued function.

CR equations for $v(x,y)$,

$$M_x=0$$

$$M_y=0$$

But it seems I am going to a wrong direction. Any solution or hints will be great helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=y+1$. Then, $u_x=v_y=1$ and $u_y=-v_x=0$. Besides, $v(0,0)=1$.

Comment: That was the trivial one, and I was thinking a non-constant one, bad luck for me. Thanks for your answer @Jose Carlos Santos. Is there any general way to think of for non-constant ones?

Comment: @falamiw I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: OK from my perspective $u(x,y)$ shouldn't contain $y$ and $v(x,y)$ shouldn't contain $x$ then tweaking them in order to resolve the function value. Am I right? @Jose Carlos Santos

Comment: I don't see why $u(x,y)$ shouldn't contain $y$ and $v(x,y)$ shouldn't contain $x$. For instance, another solution would be $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $v(x,y)=2xy+1$.

Comment: I just guess that from your solution which seems to generate a particular one. But still can't figure out how you get those solutions quickly? @Jose Carlos Santos

Comment: I think about a holomorphic function $f$ such that $f(0)=i$ and then I do $u(x,y)=\operatorname{Re}f(x+yi)$ and $v(x,y)=\operatorname{Im}f(x+yi)$. In order to get my examples, I took $f(z)=i$, $f(z)=z+i$, and $f(z)=z^2+i$.